# element styled at 100% width taking up more than 100% of parent

Tags: css

Here I have an element, `#searchField`, which takes up 80% of the width of its container. It contains elements `#searchInput` and `#mic`.

`#searchInput` is currently ~63% in width. What I would like is it to take up 100% of its container, `#searchField` and then using css3's `calc()` I will subtract 34px from that so `#mic` can fit in.

But when I style `#searchInput` to `width:100%;`, it takes up well more than 100% of `#searchField`'s width.

**How can I get `#searchInput` to take up 100% of `#searchField`'s width in a proper manner. Why isn't `width:100%;` working?**

Ultimately my plan is to style `#searchInput` at `calc(100% - 34px);` when speech-recognition is supported and when not, hide the `#mic` and do just 100% of `#searchField`.

Here is the page: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcOUVUWFM4UHFzWms/index.html

Comment: http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked into your code and found couple of things that went wrong. 
To do it right, follow the following points:

1. From `form`, remove `position: absolute;`
2. To `form`, add `margin: -16px auto 0;`
3. From `#searchField`, remove `width: 80%`and you don't need to add `position: relative` as well because you have already applied that to the `form`
4. On `#searchInput`, `padding` should be `0 0 0 42px` i.e `padding-left: 42px`. Don't give any `padding` on the right side.
5. Now, you can use `width: calc(100% - 34px)` on `#searchInput` but it won't work just yet and the reason is, you have apply `padding-left: 42px` on it. So, you should add 34px + 42px which makes it total to `width: calc(100% - 76px)`.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank yuo very much! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Set #searchField to position:relative.

Comment: Exactly. This makes calc() use that container as reference point to do its calculations.

Comment: Ah, okay. But I gave `#searchField` `position:relative;` and `#searchInput` a width of 100%, but it still is more than the width of `#searchField`

Comment: @JohanVandenRym may you help me further figure this out? More information is in the comment above.

Comment: Maybe try another approach http://cssdeck.com/labs/fluid-width-search-box - The width calc() is also taking in account the max-width set on the parent. This could get tricky.